# gradle: calling java plugin via (file) loop

Tags: java, gradle

Ive written a simple java-based plugin for gradle. I can get output from it via a simple call:

```
apply plugin: 'localtest'
mytest {
  set_filename = 'some/path'
}

...
```

And then running via

```
gradle runTest
```

I want to loop through a folder hierarchy and call the function for every file. Doing so like this:

```
FileCollection collection = fileTree(dir: '.').include('**/*.java')
collection.each { File file ->
    println file.path
    mytest { 
       set_filename = file.path
    }
}
```

If I run this as `gradle runTest` I get all the files from the directory tree printed but *my plugin only gets called for the last file in the list*.

This is the first time I've tried to do anything original with gradle so it's very likely I'm making a dumb mistake here.

Suggestions?

Comment: mytest { .. } is configuration block. It's executed before tasks. You *configure* plugin many times overriding previous settings. But your task is executed only once with the last settings.

Answer (score 1):

Currently via `mytest` extension you can set a reference to a single file. In the code sample below `... collection.each ...` in every iteration of `each` loop you are overwriting the previous file that was set - the last one wins. It won't work this way. Instead change `mytest` extension to accept *collection* instead of single file, the task to process a collection of files and then find all files you're interested in, assign them and run the task.

Comment: Or, accept one directory (as `File`) as root node and iterate through its children?

Comment: @RaGe, sure. May also be.

Comment: Is there any way to pass each filename to a separate plugin?

Comment: @ethrbunny what do you mean exactly?

Comment: I would like to call my plugin function for each file in the tree in the same way that **println** gets called.

Comment: @ethrbunny, making a separate plugin for each file name is definitely not a good idea. Instead - as I suggested in my response - change your function to accept collection in place of a single file. Then iterate the collection and invoke the logic (e.g. **println**) on every element of the collection.

Answer (score 0):

(Caveat: this probably isn't a great answer but it works)

### build.gradle

```
FileCollection collection = fileTree(dir: '/some/path').include('**/*.java')

collection.each { File file ->
    mytest {
        filename = file.path
    }
}
```

In the java plugin:

### myplugin.java

```
public class MyPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    @Override
    public void apply(Project project) {
        project.getTasks().create("mytest", MyTask.class);

    }
}
```

### MyTask.java

```
public class MyTask extends DefaultTask {
    private String filename;

    public void setFilename(String filename) throws Exception
        // this method will get called for every iteration of the gradle loop
        test(filename);
    }
}
```